# stop files from truncating objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to write some data to a file in iphone sdk....I am using a for statement to write to explain the situation better I have some code:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 11;i++){

NSString *myFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello.txt"];
[i writeToFile: myFile atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

now I expect 12345678910 to written in the file but only 10 is written in it which means file is being trncated everytime I write to file..so my question is what  can I do to write 1 to 10 WITHOUT puttting everything in a string because I have alot of data..

thanks

Comment: I'm confused by your code. The variable i is an Int and cannot be told to write to file.. Also you're overwriting the file each time you call writeToFile which is why you're left with 10 at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK documentation says this about `-writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error`:  **This method overwrites any existing file at *path*.**

That method is intended for dumping a string out to a file.  For your purposes, you can either build up a string, or open a file with `[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath]`:

```
NSString *myFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello.txt"];
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:myFile];

for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

    [file writeData:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[file closeFile];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to write a series of integers to a file, I would go about it like this:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:FILE_PATH];
for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    [fileHandle writeData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[fileHandle closeFile];
```